# excel - auto balance from previous balance and value

Tags: excel

Let's say column A contains balance and and B value (transaction value of a negative or positive number).

I'm looking for the balance to automatically work itself out.

From what I can gather so far in my quest,

```
ADDRESS(ROW()-1,1)
```

will get the cell above (I think) which would be the previous balance.

so I thought

```
=SUM(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,1)-ADDRESS(ROW()-1,2))
```

would do the trick but nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ordinary cell addressing.

In A1, put =B1

In A2, put =A1+B2

Then drag/copy A2 to the rows below as needed. Excel will increment the references.